# Full authentication is required to access this resource with Spring Security and Keycloak

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I am trying to configure my **Spring Security** with **Keycloak**. I am using **Spring Boot**. I have the following dependencies in my pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-tomcat8-adapter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I use the spring boot version **1.5.7.RELEASE**. And the keycloak version **3.2.1.Final**
And the following properties in my **application.properties**:

```
keycloak.enabled=true
keycloak.realm=test
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.resource=rest
keycloak.bearer-only=true
keycloak.credentials.secret=<secret>
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=application
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].name=spring secured api
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/api/**

management.security.enabled=false
```

I don't have any other configuration. For my endpoints I use JAX-RS.
To request my token I use the Chrome Application Postman. Here is the request:

```
POST /auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: <postman token>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password&client_id=postman&username=root&password=12345678
```

And my application request:

```
GET /api/product HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:18888
Authorization: Bearer <keycloak token from the request above>
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: <postman token>
```

But my response is:

```
{
    "timestamp": <timestamp>,
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
    "path": "/api/product"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not configuring Spring Security with Keycloak here, `security-constraints` are used to secure the servlet container and are unrelated to Spring Security. You don't need it when using SpringSecurity, add a Secuirty Config class extending `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` , check here : http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/spring-security-adapter.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have the problem that I would prefer to use a "keycloak.json" instead of using the Spring property file. At loading the application the keycloak.json is loaded. But if I try to make a rest call I get an exception that I have to set 'realm' in config. Can you help me?

Comment: in that case don't use the Spring Boot adapter and just use the Spring Security adapter, and make sure that in your `keycloak.json` th realm is specified.