# Make authenticated request to server with keycloak in Spring

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I have a Spring web server that uses Keycloak as an authentication proxy. 
I want to make a request from another server that also uses spring. For achieving this firstly I should request a token from Keycloak and then use this token to make the other requests.

I was able to make the request and get a valid token using RestTemplate:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> mapForm = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    mapForm.add("grant_type", "password");
    mapForm.add("client_id", "admin-cli");
    mapForm.add("username", "admin");
    mapForm.add("password", "admin");

    ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(AUTH_SERVER_URI, HttpMethod.POST, request, Object.class);
    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>)response.getBody();

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(mapForm, headers);

    if (map != null) {
        this.accessToken = (String)map.get("access_token");
        this.tokenType = (String)map.get("token_type");
        this.refreshToken = (String)map.get("refresh_token");
        this.expires_in = (int)map.get("expires_in");
        this.scope = (String)map.get("scope");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not a good user+password combination");
    }
```

I get the access token here ok but unfortunately after I make the request I get an 403 Forbidden Exception. This is how I make the request with the token:

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String resourceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/queries/";

    HttpEntity<QueryDTO> requestUpdate = new HttpEntity<>(queryDTO, headers);
    restTemplate.exchange(resourceUrl, HttpMethod.PUT, requestUpdate, QueryDTO.class);
```

Why am I doing wrong?

Later Edit:

The code is ok but I had to deactivated CSRF on the server side because I was making the request from a non-browser.

Comment: The 403 indicates that you have been authenticated (user/password is fine), nevertheless you don't have the rights to access whatever you want by that user. From your code I personally think that you are retrieving the token for the wrong client_id. Most likely you have defined a client for your application, so you should put this client_id to the map

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I modified the client_id to be exactly the one that my web client uses and still it didn't work... Any ideas? I get the exact same error.

Comment: this admin/admin user is also a user that has rights on the client that you have defined in keycloak?

Comment: Yes I am using the exact same username:password combinations as I am using when authenticating from the web interface.

Comment: did you use your realm in the AUTH_SERVER_URI? There is a part in the path that should reflect to your realm

Comment: Yes I did set the realm correctly.

Comment: Have you tried to access the service with postman or some other easy usable REST tool? the code itself looks ok to me, I assume that there is something wrong with the config that you use in your application or in regards of the client config in keycloak. In spring-boot you configure security-constraints that secure REST endpoints, you can specify there which roles are allowed to access the endpoint. As said the 403 IMHO points in this direction.

Comment: I realized that I get another error 
Forbidden: Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found. On the server on which I am making the request!

Comment: Now I resolved the problem with CSRF and I get another error:

Unauthorized: Full authentication is required to access this resource

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377645/full-authentication-is-required-to-access-this-resource-with-spring-security-and

Comment: @exilonX hey you got the solution? what is the AUTH_SERVER_URI you are using here

Comment: I could solve the same issue, with this article: https://medium.com/@bcarunmail/accessing-secure-rest-api-using-spring-oauth2resttemplate-ef18377e2e05
It's necessary to get a token from keycloak, which can be used with OAuthRestTemplate